# PCI-USB card not working in BIOS

Tags: usb, keyboard, bios, mouse, pci

I have got a PCI USB card for the mouse and keyboard. It works in Windows with generic drivers, but does not in BIOS.

I have a P43-DS3L Gigabyte motherboard.

On-board USB is not working. It's freezing/stopping randomly, so I can't use it.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you wanted to ask "Why doesn't it work from BIOS"?

In which case: You need drivers to use something. Your on-motherboard firmware knows precisely which hardware it shipped with and it has at least partial support for them.  If you add a random third party device then you will also need to add drivers for that. Either via a ROM on the plug in card (as done with many RAID cards, extra PXE boot options on NICs etc etc), or you cannot use them until the OS has loaded<sup>*.</sup>

---

* And that assumed that the OS has the relevant drivers or that you added them.

Comment: ok, so any recommendation on a card that would work in bios too? i am afraid mine was a cheap plug and play one. i just dont want to replace the entire motherboard.

Comment: Nope. Could try the same chipset as on board, but these days all is integrated into the NB/SB or MCH. Which leaves you with using the old fashioned PS2 ports. Connect a keyboard  to the purple port on the rear.